# Splitting a Javascript Variable into an html table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am unable to split a variable that holds 5 fields from a form into a table in 5 different sections of the same row. I would appreciate any assistance.

```js
// The section below this line is where the variable from the form input
// is inserted, but the role is not split into 5 different cells.
function getInfo() {
    var info = document.getElementById("form1");
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i=0; i < info.length; i++) {
        text += info.elements[i].value;
    }

    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = text;

    // Log the form input into the console
    console.log(text);
}
```

```css
div.ui-input-text { width: 200px !important;}
button { width: 200px !important; }
```

```html
<!-- JQuery styling and CDN files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<!-- Form HTML -->
<form id="form1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname1" required><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"  id="lname1" required><br>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address"  id="address1" required><br>
    City: <input type="text" name="city"  id="city1" required><br>
    State: <input type="text" name="state"  id="state1" required><br>

</form>
<p>Click the button below to display your entry.</p>

<!-- Javascript button to capture and display the input -->
<button onclick="getInfo()">Try it</button>

<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
        <tr id ="data">
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the table cell markup to your string, given your current approach.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- JQuery styling and CDN files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom css -->
<style>
    div.ui-input-text { width: 200px !important;}
    button { width: 200px !important; }
</style>


<title>My Web Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Form HTML -->
<form id="form1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname1" required><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"  id="lname1" required><br>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address"  id="address1" required><br>
    City: <input type="text" name="city"  id="city1" required><br>
    State: <input type="text" name="state"  id="state1" required><br>
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
    </tr>
 <tr id ="data">
 </tr>
</table>



<!-- Javascript function for the user input -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInfo() {
    var info = document.getElementById("form1");
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i=0; i < info.length; i++) {
        text += "<td>"+info.elements[i].value+"</td>";
    }

    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = text;

    // Log the form input into the console
    console.log(text);
}

</script>



<p>Click the button below to display your entry.</p>

<!-- Javascript button to capture and display the input -->
<button onclick="getInfo()">Try it</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data into different columns, you have to create the columns and append them to a row.

You do not want to concatenate the data into a single var, because you want to keep the data split up into columns.

You could do this:

```
function getInfo() {
    const info = document.getElementById("form1");
    const row  = document.getElementById("data");

    for (let i =0; i < info.length; i++) {
        // Make a new column
        const col = document.createElement('td');

        // Make a new text node
        const colText = document.createTextNode(info.elements[i].value);

        // Append text to column
        col.appendChild(colText);

        // Append column to the row (id of data)
        row.appendChild(col);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the following methods, properties, and API:

[**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

**[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**

**[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**

**[`.insertCell()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)**

**[`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)**

---

### Demo

**Details are commented in Demo**

---

```js
function distData(e) {
  //HTMLFormControlsCollection
  var F = document.forms.form1;
  var x = F.elements;

  //Convert Collection into an array
  var fieldArray = Array.from(x);
  console.log(fieldArray);

  //Reference tr#data
  var R = document.getElementById('data');

  //Each input in array will...
  fieldArray.forEach(function(field, index) {

    //Check if input has a value
    if (field.value.length > 0) {

      //Create a <td> snd insert it into R 
      var cell = R.insertCell(index);

      //Copy the input value into cell
      cell.textContent = field.value;
    } else {

      //if form control has no value ignore it
      console.log('field has no value');
    }

  });
  return false;
}
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto 20px
}

table,
td {
  border: 3px inset grey
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Web Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <style>
    div.ui-input-text {
      width: 200px
    }
    
    button {
      width: 200px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="form1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname1" required><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname1" required><br> Address: <input type="text" name="th>" id="address1" required><br> City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city1"
      required><br> State: <input type="text" name="state" id="state1" required><br>
    <button onclick='distData()' type='button'>DATA</button>
  </form>
  <p>Click the button below to display your entry.</p>



  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th colspan='2'>Name</th>
      <th colspan='3'>Location</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>State</th>
    </tr>
    The section below this line is where the variable from the form input is inserted, but the role is not split into 5 different cells.

    <tr id="data">
    </tr>
  </table>




  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are concatenating each field into a string; there is no delimiter in the string so there is no logical way to break it up. What you want to do instead is store each field in an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), then you can iterate over that to build up a HTML string, or better yet just use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create the HTML for the cells you are creating.

```js
function getInfo() {
    var info = document.getElementById("form1");
    var fields = []; // create an empty array
    var i;
    for (i=0; i < info.length; i++) {
        fields.push(info.elements[i].value);
    }

    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = '<td>' + fields.join('</td><td>') + '<td>';
}

document.getElementById('try-it').addEventListener('click', getInfo, false);
```

```css
div.ui-input-text { width: 200px !important;}
button { width: 200px !important; }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname1" required><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"  id="lname1" required><br>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address"  id="address1" required><br>
    City: <input type="text" name="city"  id="city1" required><br>
    State: <input type="text" name="state"  id="state1" required><br>

</form>
<p>Click the button below to display your entry.</p>

<button id="try-it">Try it</button>

<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id ="data">
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will work, but it produces a table that can only have one row of data in it; every time you hit "Try It" the existing data will be replaced. To add more than one row, instead of targeting a particular row and inserting cells into it, create an entire row and append it to the table. Since you are already using jQuery, I'm using it in the below example.

```js
function getInfo() {
    // Create an array containing the values of all of the fields.
    // First, select all of the input elements inside of the form,
    // Then, use .map() to extract their values, finally use .get() to
    // turn the jQuery object into an array.
    var fields = $('#form1 input').map(function () {
      return this.value;
    }).get();

    // create a new row and append it to the table.
    $('#display-table').append('<tr><td>' + fields.join('</td><td>') + '<td></tr>');
}

// instead of using in-line event handlers, attach it in your code.
$('#try-it').on('click', getInfo);
```

```css
div.ui-input-text { width: 200px !important;}
button { width: 200px !important; }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname1" required><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"  id="lname1" required><br>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address"  id="address1" required><br>
    City: <input type="text" name="city"  id="city1" required><br>
    State: <input type="text" name="state"  id="state1" required><br>

</form>
<p>Click the button below to display your entry.</p>

<button id="try-it">Try it</button>

<table id="display-table" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**More resources**

- [jQuery API reference main page](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [jQuery learning center](http://learn.jquery.com/)
- [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)
- [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)